# Raty jQuery plugin not working Rails 5

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, show, raty

I'm new to RoR and I'm having issues displaying the Raty plugin on my app. 
Also, I've noticed that another Js function has stopped working since I've added Raty so I believe there's a conflict between them?

Raty correspondent files have been added: jquery.raty.js // jquery.raty.css // images

All help would be appreciate, thank you!

*/models/product.rb*

```
def average_rating
comments.average(:rating).to_f
end
```

*/assets/javascript/application.js*

```
$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function () {

  $(".alert").delay(1500).fadeOut("slow");

});

$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function () {

  $(".notice").delay(1500).fadeOut("slow");

});
```

*/assets/javascript/site.js*

```
$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function(){
    $('.rating').raty( { path: '/assets', scoreName: 'comment[rating]' });
    $('.rated').raty({ path: '/assets',
      readOnly: true,
      score: function() {
        return $(this).attr('data-score');
      }
    });
});
```

*/views/products/_new_comment.erb*

```
<% if signed_in? %>
  <h2>Add a review:</h2>
  <%= form_for([@product, @product.comments.build]) do |f| %>
    <p>
      <%= f.label :body, "Comments" %><br>
      <%= f.text_area :body %>
    </p>
    <p>
      <%= f.label :rating, "Rating" %><br>
      <div class="rating"></div>
    </p>  
    <br>
    <p>
      <%= f.submit "Submit" %>
    </p>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

*/views/products/_comments.erb*

```
<div class="product-reviews">
    <% @comments.each do |comment| %>
        <div class="row">
            <hr>
            <p><%= comment.user.first_name %> <small><em><%= "#{time_ago_in_words(comment.created_at)} ago" %></em></small></p>
            <p><div class="rated" data-score="<%= comment.rating %>"></div></p>
            <p><%= comment.body %></p>
        </div>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

*/views/products/show.html.erb*

```
<div class="col-md-12">
    <%= render partial:'new_comment' %>
</div>

<div class="col-md-12">
    <%= render partial:'comments' %> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't copy your `config/environments/production.rb` in your question, but it probably looks like this:
`config.assets.compile = false`

If you change it to true, it should work:
`config.assets.compile = true`